# angular2 quickstart missing after 2.3 update

Tags: angular

I am unable to find the Original Angular2 Quickstart which had the package.json, tsconfig.ts, systemjs.config.js etc and standard files which the online youtube videos and tutorials use.

I found that there has been a release of Angular 2.3 and may be they have re-written the whole quickstart.

Is there a way to access the old quickstart please?

This is hampering my development process, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What version of Angular2 are you using?

Comment: I am using angular 2.3, but when i check the quick start, https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html i really cannot find the package.json, tsconfig.ts etc. they seem to be different than few days back.. all the video tutorials show the old pages and i cannot find them in the quick start. as this is a standard step before we do npm install to configure the base files for the angular app.

Comment: which version of angular2 you need ?

Answer (score 0):

The tsconfig.json file is:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false
  }
}
```

[tsconfig.json](https://github.com/angular/angular.io/blob/40f320d7210508092dc94e9f27cbf0e1fe86c266/public/docs/_examples/quickstart/ts/tsconfig.1.json)

The package.json file is:

```json
{
  "name": "angular2-quickstart",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "tsc && concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" ",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "postinstall": "typings install",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "typings": "typings"
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0",
    "@angular/upgrade": "2.0.0",

    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "systemjs": "0.19.27",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.23",

    "angular2-in-memory-web-api": "0.0.20",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^2.2.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.2",
    "typescript": "^2.0.2",
    "typings":"^1.3.2"
  }
}
```

[package.json](https://github.com/angular/angular.io/blob/40f320d7210508092dc94e9f27cbf0e1fe86c266/public/docs/_examples/quickstart/ts/package.1.json)

### EDIT 1

All of the files for the quickstart example can be found on the [git repo](https://github.com/angular/angular.io/tree/40f320d7210508092dc94e9f27cbf0e1fe86c266/public/docs/_examples/quickstart/ts) for the angular.io website. The relevent angular files are in the `app/` folder and the config files are at the root of the `quickstart/ts` folder. There is no direct link to the plunkr of the quickstart example because the embedded plunkr is generated at compile time of the website.

Comment: Yes this is fine, but still i cannot find app.module.ts standard codes etc.. these files were online earlier in the angular quickstart but can't find them..

Comment: Thank you Teddy !!

Comment: Hey @Nazeer if you feel like I answered your question correctly I would appreciate you accepting my answer.